# Trying to figure out error during assignment of a value in heap allocated memory for array

Tags: c, malloc, allocation

I am trying to figure out why I am getting an error when I assign a value to a structure in an array of structures in heap-allocated memory.

I have the follow C struct:

```
typedef struct _Point{
int x;
int y;
 }Point;
```

and an array of Point:

```
typedef Point Sample[];
```

Now I want allocate an array of Sample in witch any Sample consists of 15 Points and I using the follow code:

```
Sample *new_positions;
data.old_positions =(Sample*) malloc(sizeof(Point) * 15 * global.nsamples);
```

When I try to use it with the follow code in order to assign a value, I have an error

```
data.old_positions[0][0].x=5;
```

Where is the problem? :(

Comment: Error messages are very useful for debugging, for yourself or others.

Comment: Just a quick reminder: if you encounter an error during compilation please add the exact error message. If you encounter a problem during a run, please tell us *what kind of problem* you encountered.

Comment: the error is write access denied.

Comment: "write access denied" during compilation or execution? also letting us know the type of `data` (which is finally the cause of your problem) would be a good initiative. Please try to find out yourself first, by nailing down your problem and giving a precise description of it. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.old_positions is only single dimension -

```
 data.old_positions[0].x=5;
```

Assigns the Zeroith item.  You're better off simulating two dimensions than constructing a 2D array.

```
 data.old_positions[0 * 15 + 0].x = 5;
```

`(Sample *)malloc(...` effectively constructs a single dimensional array with no contents.  You're going to need to malloc the second dimension...

```
 data.old_positions = (Sample *)malloc(sizeof(Sample) * global.nsamples)
 for (int i = 0; i < global.nsamples; i++) 
     data.old_positions[i] = (Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point) * 15);
```

That should do it.

Comment: The code is: Sample *old_positions; old_positions =(Sample*) malloc(sizeof(Point) * 15 * global.nsamples); old_positions is an array of Sample that is an array of 15 Point therefore have 2 dimensions..